# Acquire uID from Selected Spinner That Populate with Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got input city form, where it has 2 element, `EditText` for city name and `Spinner` a that has been populate Province Data from Firebase database. I want to make nodes structure in Firebase like this:

```
database{
    provinces{
        provinceId_1{
            provinceId_1 : value
            provinceName_1 : value
        }
        provinceId_2{
            provinceId_2 : value
            provinceName_2 : value
        }
    }
    cities{
        provinceId_1{
            cityId_1{
                cityId_1 : value
                cityName_1 : value
            }
            cityId_2{
                cityId_2 : value
                cityName_2 : value
            }
        }
        provinceId_2{
            cityId_3{
                cityId_3 : value
                cityName_3 : value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i do not know how to acquire provinces id and store it to cities table in firebase database, here's my code :

```
public class AddCityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputCity;
    private Button btnAddCity, btnClearText;
    private MaterialSpinner spinnerProvinces;

    private DatabaseReference databaseCities, databaseProvinces;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_city);

        inputCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_city_edit_text);
        btnAddCity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_add_city_button);
        btnClearText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_clear_text_button);
        spinnerProvinces = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.provinceSpinner);

        databaseProvinces = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("provinces");
        databaseProvinces.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                final List<String> provinces = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DataSnapshot provinceSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String provinceName = provinceSnapshot.child("provinceName").getValue(String.class);
                    provinces.add(provinceName);
                }
                MaterialSpinner provincesSpinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.provinceSpinner);
                ArrayAdapter<String> provincesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddCityActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, provinces);         provincesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                provincesSpinner.setAdapter(provincesAdapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        btnClearText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                inputCity.setText("");
            }
        });

        btnAddCity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addCity();
            }
        });
    }
    private void addCity() {
        String name = inputCity.getText().toString().trim();
        databaseCities = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cities");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            String id = databaseCities.push().getKey();

            City city = new City(id, name);

            databaseCities.child(id).setValue(city);

            Toast.makeText(this, "City Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter City Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(AddCityActivity.this, LandingActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you generating the `provinceIds`?

Comment: The Provinces Data (provinceId and provinceName) is in firebase database, sir. It is successfully populate spinner I but do not know how to acquire provinceId from value that has already been selected by spinner